# TableLayoutPanel not showing all data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have table layout panel. Inside each one I create a Panel to insert two different controls in each cell.

I want to fill TableLayoutPanel with all my data, in this case I have 16 should have 16 different cells. So I try:

```
   private void AddRow(IList<DeliveryBreakdownGetViewModel> rModel)
        {
            tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.RowCount = rModel.Count / 4; //rModel count = 16
            tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.ColumnCount = 4;
           

            var row = 0;
            var column = 0;
            var fullRow = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < rModel.Count; i++)
            {
                var panel = new Panel();
                Labels.Add(rModel[i].DesignGroupName);
                var label = new Label
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Name = "label" + Labels.Count,
                    Text = rModel[i].DesignGroupName,
                    Location = new Point(12, YPos)
                };
                this.Controls.Add(label);
                tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.Controls.Add(panel, column, row);

                panel.Controls.Add(label);
                DeliveryBreakdownLabelsModel.Add(label);


                var numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown
                {
                    Name = "numericUpDown" + Labels.Count,
                    Maximum = decimal.MaxValue,
                    Minimum = decimal.MinValue,
                    Value = Decimal.Round(rModel[i].ContractedAmount, 2),
                    Location = new Point(12, YPos),
                    Size = new Size(60, 19),
                    DecimalPlaces = 2,

                    Tag = rModel[i].DesignGroupId
                };
                this.Controls.Add(numericUpDown);

                panel.Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
                DeliveryBreakdownNumericUpDownModel.Add(numericUpDown);

                if (fullRow % 4 == 0)
                {
                    row++;
                }

                fullRow++;
                if(column == 4)
                {
                    column = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    column++;
                }

            }
        }
```

But it only show 2 columns and 7 cells:

[image]

Why is not showing all cells and it only show 2 columns instead 4. Regards

Comment: What's your tablelayoutpanel's [growstyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.growstyle?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TableLayoutPanel_GrowStyle) set to?

Comment: I set it as:  `tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;` @ourmandave

Comment: Put a debug.writeline(fullRow, row, column) after the line where you add the panel (` tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.Controls.Add(panel, column, row);`) and see what you're getting. (Sorry, I don't know the exact syntax for writeline in c#.)

Comment: in first iteration it return fullrow = 1, column = 0 and row = 0 @ourmandave

Comment: if I use  `if(column == 3)`  now it shows 8 cells instead 7, but still missing 8 cells and 2 columns @ourmandave

Comment: What do you get for fullRow, row, & column with all iterations?